# How can I search for a Customer Payment by the check #?

Tags: quickbooks

Using QuickBooks Premier 2014, I can't figure out how to look find a Customer Payment by the check number.

What I've tried:

- The "Simple" Find (<kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>) feature also doesn't seem to have the necessary Transaction Type.
- I can use the "Advanced" Find to pull up all Payments by using the TransactionType filter, but I see no way to narrow that result by check #.

Is such a thing even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check # on a payment is the payment #, so you need to look for number, not check #.

When you search for Transaction Type: Payment, add another filter criteria **Number** (not check #). Enter the from and to numbers. If you're looking for 1 specific check # enter this number both in from and to fields.

Comment: Well, it seems so obvious in hindsight :) I think it'd be more convenient to use the Search feature in this scenario instead because the workflow is just a tiny bit quicker for me, but you can check out my answer for why that didn't work properly the first time. Arg.

Answer (score 1):

User15's answer works perfectly, but you can also use the **Search** (<kbd>F3</kbd>) feature which is a bit more of a shotgun approach. More specifically, checks can be filtered by showing results from "Transactions / Payments".

I had initially tried using Search, but it wasn't returning any results because of what appears to be a bug in my version of QuickBooks. Pasting into the Search text box using <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> duplicates the first character of the string; right-clicking to paste does not.

[image: QuickBooks Search pasting bug]

Answer (score 0):

This is easy one.  Go to Edit. Go down to Find. Click the Advance tab. On the left side go down to number. Then enter your cust. check number.

Comment: Was the Advance tab in Quickbooks 2014, or was it perhaps added since then?